# iOS crash report from apple review

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

I made an iOS app, everything was working correct. But apple reviewer got crash when he tested my app. My app crashed after he put code from sms to sign in. (I'm using firebase phone auth)

I have a crash log, can you please help me to understand what the problem?

Full log is here - http://a1257.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple128/v4/c1/63/13/c16313e4-2aa0-7b2c-6968-9074aa17a720/attachment-5924731114353171crashlog-C71A207B-D98A-4D56-B7AE-308362AFABBD.txt?downloadKey3=1508001572_c1d72ee7d5ddca59dbd48baa26ce1ed9

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have .DSYM file for your submitted IPA file?

Comment: check this url http://www.5neo.be/understanding-ios-exception-types/

Comment: Look up how to use "symbolicatecrash".  After using that successfully, the top two frames of thread #0 should point to your problem.

Comment: Looks like you have crash in UIKit something when you are trying to update from network  but the fact is thread 0 (main thread ) crashed here. if you are using swift most likely will be optional binding or forced conversion.